# Multiple private networks across multiple hosts (KVM, OpenVSwitch)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vlan, amazon-vpc, openvswitch

I had asked this question on SuperUser, looks like it wasn't the correct forum. Hopefully ServerFault is the correct one.

I am working on a project, running KVM virtualization on 4 different host with public and private network.

Currently, this is a in-house project (don't expect much from the public network).

What intrigues me is the private network. I have set up vlan tagging with OvS and currently use about 15 different (setup in vlan trunk).

The part that intrigues me is that switches are limited to 4096 (-2) usuable vlan ids. If looking at a scale, 4094 vlans are not that many for bigger companies like AWS, Azure, GCP. Specially if each client has more than 1 private network, then it would not be possible to create more than 4094 private networks across hosts.

How does AWS VPC, GCP or even Azure make it so that they can have many virtual machines with same subnets and still have host to host packet while making sure no users packet gets to another users private network. Are there any techniques to creating more VLANs (or maybe something else than vlans?).

Thanks in advance!

ASM

Comment: Most likely with VXLAN.

Comment: @Michael-Hampton Thanks! Definitely looks like a possible option! I'll try to see if I can set up one for fun and see how it performs.